I have the Tempo and Signature of a song, how do I find the length between eighth-notes
I have the Tempo (108.173) and Time Signature (3/4) of a song, how do I determine the milliseconds of time between each eighth-note that is played?
I'm trying to make a piano autoplayer, and I need to know the duration of time to wait between each eighth-note.

What do you mean by "piano autoplayer"? What are you going to "play", MIDI files or anything else? I sincerely doubt that you would only need eighth values. In any case, the formula is relatively simple: the tempo is based on the meter, if it's a simple meter (eg: x/4), then you get the duration of each "beat" (a quarter) dividing 60 seconds by the tempo (eg: if it's 120, each quarter beats lasts 0.5 seconds), therefore eighth notes last half that time. But, as said, if you're "making" a player, it's quite likely you'll get quite different durations and tempo markings.

What units are being measured by Tempo?

Answers may be more helpful for you if you explain what you're having trouble with: music definitions, time units, the math calculations, something else?

This question is similar to: How can I find the length in seconds of a quarter-note (crotchet) if I have a tempo marking?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In 3/4 time you say a quarter note occurs 108.173 times in a minute. An eighth note is twice as fast and occurs 216.346 times a minute. Divide by 60 and that gives you 3.60576667 eighth notes a second. One second divided by the number of eighth notes in a second gives you 277.3 milliseconds between eighth notes.
The upper number of the time signature doesn’t matter. The denominator of 4 tells you a quarter note is the unit of measurement.

I believe it's theoretically simpler (and conceptually more adequate) to divide 60 by the tempo and then multiplying by the relative fraction: 60 / 108.173 * (note duration) / (beat length)


...I need to know the duration of time to wait between each eighth-note

There is no time between the eighth notes, not unless there are also rests.
What you are really asking is how long is the duration of an eighth note.
The tempo of 108 (rounded down for simplicity) is the number of beats per minute. A tempo of 108 is 108 beats per minute.
A time signature of 3/4 means the beats are marked with a quarter note.
An eighth note is half the duration of a quarter note.
There are 60 seconds in a minute and 1,000 milliseconds in a second.
OK, there rest is just calculations, which I did like this...
1 minute = 60 seconds = 60000 milliseconds

108 bpm (beats per minute)
108 beats per 60 seconds

60 / 108 = 0.555 seconds per beat

Quarter note gets the beat

0.555 seconds per quarter note

Eighth note is half the duration of a quarter note

0.555 / 2 = 0.2775 seconds per eighth note

Or, you could say eighth notes are "half beats" and double the bpm tempo number from 108 to 216.

60 / 216 = 0.277 seconds per eighth note

0.277 * 1000 = 277 milliseconds per eighth note

So, your eighth note duration is roughly 277 milliseconds. Set your decimal precision and round however you like.
